# mysql - find the number of occurrences from two columns

Tags: mysql

question example :

```
source | target
apple  |   dog
dog    |   cat
door   |   cat
dog    |   apple
cat    |   dog
```

result :

```
apple dog 2
dog   cat 2
door  cat 1
```

Here is my question, as an example:

I am trying to count the `apple` and `dog` occurrence from source and target. The
count is 2, that is; `apple dog` and `dog cat`.

In the same way; `dog cat` and `cat dog`, they occur 2 times.

How can I do this with `mysql` ?

the data will be very large, so this is just a simple example.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking, please elaborate with what you have tried and what you are struggling with.

Comment: Are you looking for combinations `cat dog`, `apple dog`? Or just `dog` with a random `target` or `source`?

Comment: Start with this... SELECT GREATEST(source,target),LEAST(source,target) FROM my_table;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Source` and `Target` are joined with an ID I would do this as:

```
SELECT
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue,
    COUNT(*) As MyCount
FROM
(SELECT
    SourceTable.Value FirstValue,
    TargetTable.Value SecondValue
FROM
    SourceTable 
    INNER JOIN TargetTable ON SourceTable.IDValue = TargetTable.IDValue
UNION ALL
SELECT
    TargetTable.Value FirstValue,
    SourceTable.Value SecondValue
FROM
    TargetTable 
    INNER JOIN SourceTable ON TargetTable.IDValue = SourceTable.IDValue) 
GROUP BY
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue
```

Reading the question again I'm unsure if these are two columns in the same table. If they are then the query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue,
    COUNT(*) As MyCount
FROM
(SELECT
    SourceColumn FirstValue,
    TargetColumn SecondValue
FROM
    MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT
    TargetColumn FirstValue,
    SourceColumn SecondValue
FROM
    MyTable) 
GROUP BY
    FirstValue,
    SecondValue
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see, your issue is: to count your values independent of their order in your columns. So, pair `<'foo', 'bar'>` should be counted as `<'bar', 'foo'>`. For that you may use:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  test 
GROUP BY 
  LEAST(source, target),
  GREATEST(source, target)
```

Note, that:

- Mixing non-group columns with group function will work in MySQL only. It's an [extension](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html), so server is free to chose any row.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (source VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,target VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,PRIMARY KEY(source,target)
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 ('apple','dog'),
 ('dog','cat'),
 ('door','cat'),
 ('dog','apple'),
 ('cat','dog');

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +--------+--------+
 | source | target |
 +--------+--------+
 | apple  | dog    |
 | cat    | dog    |
 | dog    | apple  |
 | dog    | cat    |
 | door   | cat    |
 +--------+--------+


 SELECT GREATEST(source,target),LEAST(source,target),COUNT(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY GREATEST(source,target),LEAST(source,target);
 +-------------------------+----------------------+----------+
 | GREATEST(source,target) | LEAST(source,target) | COUNT(*) |
 +-------------------------+----------------------+----------+
 | dog                     | apple                |        2 |
 | dog                     | cat                  |        2 |
 | door                    | cat                  |        1 |
 +-------------------------+----------------------+----------+
```